# How to override method which is overloaded in parent class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a class that extends `Logger` from [`bunyan`](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan).

Here's the declaration for the original class `Logger`:

```js
declare class Logger {
    trace(): boolean
    trace(error: Error, ...params: any[]): void;
    trace(obj: Object, ...params: any[]): void;
    trace(format: any, ...params: any[]): void;
}
```

Here are some of my failed attempts at override `Logger#trace`:

```js
class FooLogger extends Logger {
    trace(error: Error, ...params: any[]): void {
        // Property 'trace' in type 'FooLogger' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Logger'.
        // Type '(error: Error, ...params: any[]) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (): boolean; (error: Error, ...params: any[]): void; (obj: Object, ...params: any[]): void; (format: any, ...params: any[]): void; }'.(2416)
    }
}

class FooLogger1 extends Logger {
    trace(obj: Object, ...params: any[]): void {
        // Property 'trace' in type 'FooLogger1' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Logger'.
        //Type '(obj: Object, ...params: any[]) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (): boolean; (error: Error, ...params: any[]): void; (obj: Object, ...params: any[]): void; (format: any, ...params: any[]): void; }'.(2416)  }
    }
}

class FooLogger2 extends Logger {
    trace(format: any, ...params: any[]): void {
        // Property 'trace' in type 'FooLogger2' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Logger'.
        // Type '(format: any, ...params: any[]) => void' is not assignable to type '{ (): boolean; (error: Error, ...params: any[]): void; (obj: Object, ...params: any[]): void; (format: any, ...params: any[]): void; }'.(2416)
    }
}

class FooLogger3 extends Logger {
    trace(format?: any, ...params: any[]): void | boolean {
        // Property 'trace' in type 'FooLogger3' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'Logger'.
        // Type '(format?: any, ...params: any[]) => boolean | void' is not assignable to type '{ (): boolean; (error: Error, ...params: any[]): void; (obj: Object, ...params: any[]): void; (format: any, ...params: any[]): void; }'.
        //  Type 'boolean | void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
        //  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.(2416)
    }
}
```

What is the correct way to write `FooLogger#trace` so that it correctly matches `Logger#trace`?

Comment: something caught my attention not sure if it was the root of your problem. in your Logger class I think you should have a semicolon after the word boolean

Comment: `trace(...args: any[]): boolean { return false; }` will match.  or you can just have your subclass use an overloaded `trace()` method with a bunch of call signatures like the parent class.

Comment: [subclass with overload example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwDIHsDm2Q3gG8BYAKHngBcYowQAKASgC54AjTTCEKAOzIrVaDfDEwxWAURhiYAGngA6ZQAdYUALbJWfAJ4BtALot4AN0wBLYAG4BVGnXqY2AK1YB5V+EoLlitTRaOrwGxqzmVrbk9sL0AGbiGlCUwbq+qupB8HpGJhE2ZAC+ZGRIqPAAGvAgAB6UILzAaFi4+ER2Qo4mHFw8-NGdIjLiUsPyShmB2tkhueGWBQMODM5u8Kve6f6Z0zlhZgtRgsvxicmpWwGau7P7+UcxjrDYAIwA-BcTis83od2c3D48AAPgcrO1ohQLHF4PRKLoVCBMDDni94ABeTHwABEAFdGiA4hZeCBgNjGPA4JRcTBePZcSAHlCYfRUfBichKHw6Mj4NJZBSSJD4HYKIVqhBkAhobD4YjeWzMeicRswJRyRDRfBxSBJQghVritEjUayEA)